# Is there a native option to keep the screen on if there is an any application open on the screen?

Tags: android-13, samsung-one-ui

Sometimes I need the screen to remain active on a website where it updates news in real time without needing to refresh the page manually or on a football game application that updates the scores in real time without needing to refresh the page either.

But the device does not detect these updates and the screen turns off.

Is there an option that realizes that there is an app open on the screen so the screen will not turn off?

Comment: In developer options (enabled by tapping build number 7 or more times) there is an option for *stay awake* (screen will *never sleep* while charging). You can enable that and keep the device connected to power source for charging// Note that this bad for battery health unless it is for occasional use//Is your device rooted?

Comment: Also check if your display is an LCD or an OLED. If it is the latter don't let the display stay on for too long because this can cause the OLED to burn-in certain parts of the screen so they stay as physical ghost images.

Answer (score 1):

## [Coffee](https://github.com/mueller-ma/Coffee)

> This Android app allows you to keep the display awake without having to change the device settings. It can be toggled at various places:
>
> - A tile in the quick settings, the place that holds the toggles for e.g. Wi-Fi and Bluetooth. Requires Android 7 or higher.
> - A button in the app itself
> - A shortcut on your home screen. It can be created in the app, if your launcher supports it.
>
> Coffee can be set as assist app (Device settings => Apps => Default apps => Assist app) and changes it's state when assist is called.